# Cloud-init not executing on Fedora 16

Tags: amazon-ec2, fedora, cloud-init

Cloud init does not come with the base instance I uploaded from Amazon(Fedora 16 x86_64), so I installed using

```
sudo yum install cloud-init
```

Now when I launch this instance via

```
ec2-run-instance -f my_bash_script
```

It copies `my_bash_script` to `/var/lib/cloud/instances/user-data.txt`

However, none of the commands in the script seem to be executed (mainly initializing chef)

I read online that CentOS uses user-data scripts get initialized from `cloud-init-user-script` on first boot. I assumed this would be the case with Fedora too, but this script does not exist on my system.

I ran

```
grep 'user-data.txt' /var/log/cloud-init.log
```

and it returned no results.

How can I get this configured correctly on Fedora so that I can execute user-data scripts upon instance creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue was, that cloud-init was rushed into F16 at the last minute. As a result, out of the box, cloud-init only works with cloud-config setup. In order to get fedora to work with user-data input scripts, I decided to use a Fedora 18 AMI, where this functionality is included by default.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether your script given in user-data got created as executable script under `/var/lib/cloud/instances/scripts/` if it got created then the init part has completed successfully.

After that `cloud-init-cfg all final` command needs to be executed and that's the one which calls the `cloud_final_modules` part of parameters in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` file. Hence create a new service which can execute that command and the service should be named such that it run after the `cloud-init` service.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This might be the way to get user-data inputs working with F16. I figured out that the cloud-init user-data option did not work out of the box with F16, so I decided to use F18 instead, and it worked.